# iPhone Sqlite insert running on nsthread

Tags: iphone, ios5, sqlite, xcode4.3

Im developing an application in which i need to insert a huge amount of data into sqlite database. The data gets inserted properly but the issue is some times i get an exception that

---

```
Assertion failure in -[AttendeeDetails addData:anddbpath:], /Users/abhisheknaidu/Desktop/EventApp/AttendeeDetails.m:118
2012-08-14 11:54:24.937 EventApp[3586:1770b]
```

*** `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Error while creating add statement. 'SQL logic error or missing database''`

This only happens some times ..

Can anyoneone here help me out in this..

im using the below code for inserting

```
- (void) addData:(NSMutableArray *)attendeeArray anddbpath:(NSString *)dbPath{

    NSString *str = @"Not Available";
    if(addStmt == nil) {
          if (sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {

        const char *sql = "insert into AttendeeDetails(AtQRid , EventId , ImageUrl , FirstName , LastName , Company , Email , PhoneNumber , City , State , ATBarcodeID) Values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &addStmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
            NSAssert1(0, @"Error while creating add statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
        }
        sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 1, [[attendeeArray valueForKey:@"Attendee_QR_ID"] UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 2, [[[[AppDelegate SharedInstance].DetailsOfEventArray valueForKey:@"Event_ID"] objectAtIndex:0] UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        if ([attendeeArray valueForKey:@"Image_URL"] == [NSNull null]) {
            sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 3, [str UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        }
        else {
            sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 3, [[attendeeArray valueForKey:@"Image_URL"] UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        }
        sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 4, [[attendeeArray valueForKey:@"FirstName"] UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 5, [[attendeeArray valueForKey:@"LastName"] UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        if ([attendeeArray valueForKey:@"Company"] == [NSNull null]) {
            sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 6, [str UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        }
        else {
            sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 6, [[attendeeArray valueForKey:@"Company"] UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        }

        if ([attendeeArray valueForKey:@"Email"] == [NSNull null]) {
            sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 7, [str UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        }
        else {
            sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 7, [[attendeeArray valueForKey:@"Email"] UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        }

        if ([attendeeArray valueForKey:@"PhoneNo"] == [NSNull null]) {
            sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 8, [str UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        }
        else {
            sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 8, [[attendeeArray valueForKey:@"PhoneNo"] UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        }


        if ([attendeeArray valueForKey:@"City"] == [NSNull null]) {
            sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 9, [str UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        }
        else {
            sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 9, [[attendeeArray valueForKey:@"City"] UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        }

        if ([attendeeArray valueForKey:@"State"] == [NSNull null]) {
            sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 10, [str UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        }
        else {
            sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 10, [[attendeeArray valueForKey:@"State"] UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        }

        if ([attendeeArray valueForKey:@"State"] == [NSNull null]) {
            sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 10, [str UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        }
        else {
            sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 10, [[attendeeArray valueForKey:@"State"] UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        }


        if ([attendeeArray valueForKey:@"State"] == [NSNull null]) {
            sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 11, [str UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        }
        else {
            sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 11, [[attendeeArray valueForKey:@"State"] UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        }

        if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(addStmt))
            NSAssert1(0, @"Error while inserting data. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
        else
            //SQLite provides a method to get the last primary key inserted by using sqlite3_last_insert_rowid
            coffeeID = sqlite3_last_insert_rowid(database);

        //Reset the add statement.
        sqlite3_reset(addStmt);
    }
    addStmt = nil;

}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

i think you can use dispatch queue

```
    dispatch_queue_t concurrentQueue =  dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);

    dispatch_async(concurrentQueue, ^{
      //this will call when you inserting in bg


        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
           //this will call when inserting  is finished
        });
    });
```

Comment: @ankur i still get the same exception as
 *** Assertion failure in -[AttendeeDetails addData:anddbpath:], /Users/abhisheknaidu/Desktop/EventApp/AttendeeDetails.m:118
2012-08-14 12:46:25.771 EventApp[1020:1a03] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Error while creating add statement. 'SQL logic error or missing database''
im using this